# Is possible to show createMaterialTopTabNavigator on only one screen in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-router

I have multiple screens in react native app I would like to show createMaterialTopTabNavigator on only specified screen, not on all.
Is there a possibility to achieved this?

Answer (score 0):

We can use tabBarVisible in navigation options.

const MyTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({HomeStackNavigator, DashboardStackNavigator},TabNavigatorConfig);

const HomeStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({Home}, {tabBarVisible: false})
const DashboardStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({Dashboard}, {tabBarVisible: true})

[See the description here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html)

Answer (score 0):

then we can use tabBarVisible:false in navigationOption with indivisual screen.
Ex:

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    HomeScreen: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: "Home",
            tabBarIcon:
                
        }
    },

```
LenderScreen: {
    screen: LenderScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Lend",
        tabBarIcon:
            <Image source={require('../assets/images/images/ic_lend.png')} style={{ height: 20, width: 20 }} />,
        tabBarVisible: false,
    },
},
```

)